# How to use wget to download all URLs matching a pattern

Tags: wget

Say I have a website like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/dir1/id-1
https://mywebsite.com/dir1/id-2
https://mywebsite.com/dir1/id-3
https://mywebsite.com/dir2/foo-id-1
https://mywebsite.com/dir2/foo-id-2
https://mywebsite.com/dir2/foo-id-3
https://mywebsite.com/dir3/list-1
https://mywebsite.com/dir3/list-2
https://mywebsite.com/dir3/list-...
https://mywebsite.com/dir3/list-n
https://mywebsite.com/dir4/another-list-type-1
https://mywebsite.com/dir4/another-list-type-2
https://mywebsite.com/dir4/another-list-type-...
https://mywebsite.com/dir4/another-list-type-n
https://mywebsite.com/random-other-directories-i-dont-care-about...
```

I would like to download all the `/dir1/:id` and `/dir2/foo-:id` pages, but would like to follow the links from all the pages in `/dir1` through `/dir4`, where some of those directories are just lists of links to `/dir/:id` for example.

Wondering how I do this. Ideally it would maximize downloading all the `:id` links *first*, rather than getting stuck downloading the thousands or millions of list pages first.

Wondering how to do that. It is not just a simple "mirror the site". A lot of the time when I've tried this, wget gets overly absorbed in links I don't care about. I want it to _maximize downloading `/dir1/:id` and `/dir2/foo-:id`, while also gathering whatever links it finds on other pages it encounters. Basically, some way to prioritize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want neither a breadth-first nor a depth-first approach, but rather one that uses some notion of priorities.

This is unfortunately not possible purely with Wget. However, with a little bash scripting, you might be able to get quite close. There are 2 simple approaches I can think of:

1. Give Wget the link to `/dir1/` and `/dir2/` first and let it recursively download  that. Once it is done, invoke wget with `mywebsite.com/` in order to download the rest of the files. It will waste a few seconds sending `HEAD` requests for all the files you've already downloaded, but that's it.
2. This is similar to (1) above. Except, you invoke wget with a ``--accept-regex` for each of the directories, causing them to downloaded one after another